# unable to set initial pose in gazebo spawn_urdf_model (groovy)

Tags: ros, pose, spawn-model, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've just updated from Fuerte to Groovy, and seem to have lost the ability to spawn an object at a given pose. Steps that reproduce this reproduce this problem (after updating to groovy):

```
roslaunch gazebo_worlds empty_world.launch
rosrun xacro xacro.py `rospack find gazebo_worlds`/objects/table.urdf.xacro > /tmp/table.urdf
rosrun gazebo spawn_model -urdf -file /tmp/table.urdf -x 2 -y 2 -z 2 -model table_model
```

The table will spawn at (0,0,0). Can someone confirm if this is a bug?

Also should the Gazebo ROS wrapper questions (like this one) be asked at answers.gazebosim.org?

Thanks!!

###Edit#1

**Thread continued at [answers.gazebosim](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1097/unable-to-set-initial-pose-in-gazebo/)**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51295/unable-to-set-initial-pose-in-gazebo-spawn_urdf_model-(groovy)/) by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2871 on 2013-01-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To your 2nd question,

> Also should the Gazebo ROS wrapper questions (like this one) be asked at answers.gazebosim.org?

@natekoenig [says all Qs should be posted on gazebosim](http://code.ros.org/lurker/message/20120925.160824.7c8d5f5f.es.html).

(but I feel it's confusing to pure `Gazebo` users to see `ROS`-`Gazebo` topics there)

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-01-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0